# Аудио воспроизводится во всех браузерах, кроме Chrome Android

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, frontend, web-audio

С чем может быть связано то обстоятельство, что дорожка проигрывается в настольных версиях Гугх Хрома и Мозилы, в мобильной версии Мозилы, но не в мобильной версии Хрома. К тому же смотрю на код страницы в мобильной версии Хрома и там есть те строки кода, которые во всех других браузерах аудио воспроизводят

```
<audio autoplay>
    <source src="audio/sound.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="audio/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <a href="audio/sound.mp3">Скачать name.mp3</a>
</audio>
```

Comment: Возможно с тем, что автоплей запрещён? Попробуйте добавить controls и запустить воспроизведение вручную

Comment: @andreymal Да, вручную воспроизводится. Благодарю. А есть возможность обойти этот запрет на мобильных хром?